# mysql SSL is required but the server doesn't support it

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssl-certificate, mysql-replication

i generated these files in my master machine :

```
openssl genrsa 4096 > ca-key.pem 

openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 9999 -key ca-key.pem > ca-cert.pem 
 
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -days 9999 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem > server-req.pem
 
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 9999 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > server-cert.pem

openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -days 9999 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem > client-req.pem
 
openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 9999 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > client-cert.pem
```

and then update `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` like:

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 1
binlog-format = mixed
log-bin = mysql-bin
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog=1
 
ssl
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/certs/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/certs/server-key.pem
```

then i copied ca-cert.pem, client-cert.pem and client-key.pem to my slave machine `/etc/mysql/certs`

my issue is i cant communicate while i run from slave

`mysql -h 192.168.1.53 -u replication -p --ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem`

got error
`ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't support it`

what is the issue and how to fix? also i tried `mysql -h localhost -u replication -p --ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/mysql/certs/client-key.pem` in master itself and get same error